# Core Data or ASIHTTPRequest Cache?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, asihttprequest

I'm building an app that gets all data from a web service.

At the moment, I store the data received from the service using Core Data to basically cache it.

I've been using ASIHTTPRequest to do all my service calls and reading through the docs today, I saw that it features a built in cache facility where by it stores the data disk.

I'd like to switch to the ASIHTTPRequest cache. Does anyone know if there is a particular advantage to using Core Data over the built in ASIHTTPRequest cache feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core Data isn't primarily a persistence API, instead it is an API to build the entire model layer of a Model-View-Controller app. If you abandon Core Data, you lose all the automatic data model management and have to write it yourself.

If the app is very simple and e.g. just a list of data, you are not familiar with Core Data then rolling your own data model might be a quicker solution.

However, it usually isn't. Before deciding, you should set down and see how much supporting code you will have to write in order to get the data in the ASIHTTPRequest cache into the UI.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. They're pretty much completely different things really, I hadn't thought. I'll stick with Core Data and try and utilise the ASIHTTPRequest caching where possible.